# I am simply trying to write a simple function in gnuplot that fits the data in data.dat to a Gaussian distribution

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I am attempting to fit a Gaussian fit to a set of data in gnuplot.

I set variables:

```
A = 1
w = 1
xave = 1
```

The function

```
N(x) =  (A/(sqrt(2*3.1416)*w)) * exp(-(x-xave)**2/(2*(w**2)))
```

is to be fit. When I perform:

```
fit N(x) 'data.dat' via A, w, xave
```

I get the errror: could not open log-file fit.log

Any explanations on why?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a permission problem. Are you allowed to write on the current directory? Try the same procedure in a folder where you have all the permissions and see what happens. I made a test in a folder where I did not have write permissions, and got the same error. Try this:

```
set fit logfile '/tmp/tmpGNU'
```

This will write the output on the /tmp folder, in which you should have writing privileges. See if that works.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this via creating special directory at C:
`C:\comp\...`
and saving files there.